# Hbase - Hadoop : TableInputFormat extension

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Using an hbase table as my input, of which the keys I have pre-processed in order to consist of a number concatenated with the respective row ID, I want to rest assured that all rows with the same number heading their key, will be processed from the same mapper at a M/R job. I am aware that this could be achieved through extension of TableInputFormat, and I have seen one or two posts concerning extension of this class, but I am searching for the most efficient way to do this in particular.

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PrefixFilter in your scan.
http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/PrefixFilter.html

And parallelize the launch of your different mappers using Future

```
final Future<Boolean> newJobFuture = executor.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            Job mapReduceJob = MyJobBuilder.createJob(args, thePrefix,
                    ...);
            return mapReduceJob.waitForCompletion(true);
        }
    });
```

But I believe this is more an approach of a reducer you are looking for.